# Jenkins Pipeline : How to access plugin contributed Global Configuration values

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm working on a Jenkins Pipeline script and ran into a case where I need to get a value that is set in the Jenkins Global Configuration.  The Manage Jenkins : Configure System page is where I set a value for one of the plugins installed.  The plugin provides a configuration line to add a URL (Confluence URL).   I want to access the URL in my pipeline to use for a specialize step.  The issue I'm having is I'm unsure how to get a global configuration defined by a plugin.  Is there a way to access global configuration values from a pipeline?  Or would the plugin have to expose it?

Comment: You can probably use something by `import`ing from Jenkins within the Groovy code. I am unsure if it is possible for the plugin to expose at that scope, so probably the former.

Comment: Not sure i understand.  My pipeline script is using the sciprted pipeline (not declarative).   My current workaround it to put the value in the Jenkinsfile but was hoping to use what jenkins configuration already held to simplify setup.